# URL aliases and Entity Translation (menu name replacement pattern)

Tags: path-aliases, i18n-l10n

I am using entity translation (Field translation) for my nodes, and set the menu name on each 'page'.
The menu itself is arrange to basically have a duplicate tree in the same menu each with a different language, for example:

```
main-menu
-item 1 english
--sub item 1 english <node/23>
-item 1 german
--sub item 1 german <node/23>
```

Now when i want to make URL aliases based on the menu it does not translate.

```
[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:menu-link]
```

Keeps the URL as english. i assume this is because of "node".

What replacement patterns could i use to make the URL aliases compatible with my entity translation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `[node:menu-link]`, use `[node:title]` instead.